# Why my concurrentSkipListSet stucks while multi add?

Tags: java.util.concurrent

I want to test the performance of ConcurrentSkipListSet vs. ConcurrentLinkedQueue,so I make a test:

```
ConcurrentSkipListSet<Integer> concurrentSkipListSet=new ConcurrentSkipListSet<>((o1,o2)->{return 1;});
HashSet<Callable<Integer>> sets=new HashSet<>();
for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
    final int j=i;
    sets.add(()->{concurrentSkipListSet.add(j);
        System.out.println(j);
            return null;
    });
}
Long c=System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println(c);
ExecutorService service=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
try {
    service.invokeAll(sets);
}catch(Exception e){}
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()-c);
```

I am so confused that the program stucks after sout about 20~50 j,and it won't finish in about an hour. If I change the i as i<10,it finished at 3 millis sometimes or stucks after sout about 4~5 j sometimes.

A newCachedThreadPool perfroms same as the newFixedThreadPool in IDEA and Eclipse.

Please help me to analyze it,3Q.

Now I think it is not the newCachedThreadPool's problem but that concurrentSkipListSet.add(j);
when I changed SkipList to LinkedQueue or a synchronized HashSet, it worked well and finished in 168 millis or 170 millis.

Please help me to analyze it,3Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be in the comparator you're supplying to the `ConcurrentSkipListSet` constructor. It's always returning 1 which may lead to some kind of infinite loop in `ConcurrentSkipListSet` implementation. You could use `ConcurrentSkipListSet` constructor with no parameters to use natural ordering for `Integer`.

Consider what's going on when you're always returning 1 from a comparator:

Suppose we have two object A and B. A sorting algorithm at some point may ask your comparator "is A greater then B?" calling `compare(A, B)`. You return 1 which means that indeed A > B and B should precede A in sorted order. Then at some point there's a chance that the algorithm will ask "is B greater then A?" and your `compare(B, A)` also will return 1 which means B > A and A should precede B in sorted order.

You can see that this comparator behavior is completely inconsistent. For some algorithms this may lead to infinite loops. For instance an algorithms may endlessly swap a pair of elements.

Comment: Yes, what @algrid said - ConcurrentSkipList is a sorted collection, but you're making all of the values equal, which many (otherwise high performance) sort algorithms are going to have difficulty with.  Try it without providing the comparator.

Comment: @algrid When I want to sort the elements by adding order, how should I do without always returning 1? Replaced by a ConcorrentLinkedQueue?Actually always return -1 works well.....

Comment: @GregHNZ    I tried my best to read the source code of ConcorrectSkipListMap's doPut(), which is the practical method in add(). I think always "return 1" makes the skipList  intersected. It may take more time to find the right place while doPut() , but I think it won't come to a deadlock for the search only goes down or right.  However, it stucks instead of being slow while always "return 1" . I have no idea of it now, please help me.

Comment: @user8368911 I added more explanations. If you want "adding order" then using a queue looks more reasonable.